# Partial Form Class C# - Only display code view for class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a Blank Forms project in C#.

I wanted to separate the functions and events into different Codefiles on the Form Class. In order to make it more manageable when it becomes large and multiple people are using it on CodeControl.

So I created;

- `Form1.Functions.cs`
- `Form1.Events.cs`

These extra partial classes both consist of

```
namespace MyLargeProject
{
    public partial class Form1
    {

    } 

}
```

I also changed the `csproj` file so the VS IDE would make them appear in the Soution Explorer.

Example

```
<Compile Include="Forms\Form1.Functions.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

So the program compiles and all is looking good except that when I open the file from the solution explorer it opens up a blank Form designer, and not the code.

I want VS to only open this class as a code file to limit issues with the Form1.Designer.cs file.

I have also tried removing the SubType

```
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
```

but Visual Studio keeps adding it back to the csproj file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned on the comments, Visual Studio will open any file ending with `.Designer.cs` in the code editor rather than on the forms designer. Taking advantage of this, a good solution to have a form not open in the form designer is to name the file that contains the class with ending `.Designer.cs`.

*Note*: I would say this is not elegant. I find it counter intuitive to have a file named `Form1.Designer.cs` and don't have a designer for it. Also, if the form was originally created with the forms designer, this will require to merge `Form1.cs` and `Form1.Designer.cs` which can be problematic from within Visual Studio.

---

*My original answer*

Follow these steps:

1) Make sure the designer is closed.

2) Modify your `Form1.Designer.cs` and add the attribute `DesignerCategory` with the empty string `""` (any random value other than "Designer", "Form" or "Component" also works - case insensitive):

```
namespace MyLargeProject
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]
    public partial class Form1
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

3) Unload your project.

4) Reload your project.

5) Notice the designer doesn't appear.

6) Enjoy!

*Note*: tested on Visual Studio 2012, yet based on a [discussion thread from 2005](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64c77755-b0c1-4447-8ac9-b5a63a681b78/partial-class-for-a-form-problem?forum=csharpide).

Comment: 99% OK, it made the whole project only open as code and not using the designer. but this is definitely a big step forward.

Comment: @IEnumerable in VS 2012 it works only for the marked form. As I'm unable to test on VS 2010 I would guess it is a bug of VS 2010. I don't know if there are any workarounds.

Comment: Actually Im going to mark this as correct, please modify your answer as in the thread you posted was the correct answer. Just by changing the extention from `.cs` to `.Designer.cs` the file will always load in the Code view.

Comment: I agree its not elegant, but the original solution would change all files to open in the Code view rather than Form1.cs opening by designer. (at least on my installation).

From my current test its all going well. `[Im using C# Express 2010.]`

Having the `Form1.Events.Designer.cs` extension is not great, would have preferred the `Form1.Events.cs` but for now and this project it will have to do. 

Thanks for your help :)