# Is it possible use C# partial WinForm class files without seeing a form icon in Solution Explorer?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a utility VS 2013 Winform application that consists of a `TabControl` and about six tab pages. Most of the tabs are used to edit table data in one way or another.

I created multiple .cs files dividing the Form into multiple partial classes that have the specific event support for the controls on that tab.

The functionality that the events call are in classes elsewhere in the project.

This gives me a nice separation of concerns at least by file for the form class. I like this better than having #regions in the main form file.

The downside is that each of these files has a Form icon and looks like a separate form, making finding the one other form in this project harder to notice. It feels like a code smell.

Is there a better way to break this apart and still be able to use the designer to layout the tab pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't "remove the form icon" but may help you with organizing your code.

What you can do is nest all of the additional partial class files all under the single, original form.

So, I started with a basic forms application with `Form1` and then added an extra partial class, within the file `Form1_button.cs` to contain some extra code, and got what I believe is something similar to your current situation:

[image: Before nesting]

I then unload the project, and make the following edit within the `.csproj` file. I locate the entry for this file:

```
    <Compile Include="Form1_button.cs">
        <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
```

And add a `DependentUpon` element:

```
    <Compile Include="Form1_button.cs">
        <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
        <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
```

And then reload the project:

[image]

And this way, you're using partial classes but they're all organized hierarchically under a single "form icon" and, of course, it should now be easy to find the other form you refer to since there should only be two form nodes in the solution explorer.